# ColdFusion webservice for iOS

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I need an iOS app to be able to access a database. I know a backend has to be a web service that handles the DB request.

There are a wealth of tutorials available to do this with php. I have not found anything about writing this web service with ColdFusion.

Is it not possible?

Comment: What method did you use to try to find out how to write a ColdFusion web service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start by looking at [the documentation on how to write a REST web service](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-5719eac51353e6bb244-8000.html) for ColdFusion. It should give you a good starting point.

If after this you are having a specific problem with your web service, then ask that on Stack Overflow.